# Обновить DataSource без очистки DataSet

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

Есть два метода: на заполнение таблицы (`LoadData`) и обновление таблицы после изменений (`ReloadData`).

```
private void LoadData()
{
    dB_Order = new DB_Order();
    dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `tbl_orders`", dB_Order.getConnection());
    dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tbl_orders");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["tbl_orders"];
}

private void ReloadData()
{
    dataSet.Tables["tbl_orders"].Clear();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "tbl_orders");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["tbl_orders"];
}
```

Вопрос: можно ли как-то обновить таблицу `DataGridView` без использования `dataSet.Tables["tbl_orders"].Clear()`? Т.к. с ним скролл кидает на первую строку.

Пробовал передавать строку которая сейчас активна, и после заполнения `DataSource` выбирать эту строку `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Selected = true`, но это тоже не лучше решение.

Comment: у датагридвью кажется был метод .refresh(); Попробуй вызвать.

Comment: @Andrew Увы, он не работает. Когда убираю `dataSet.Tables["tbl_orders"].Clear()`, то данные таблицы дублируются, а `dataGridView1.Refresh()` вообще не дает никакого результата.

Comment: еще есть вариант пройтись по всем ячейкам нужным и сделать их drity

Comment: @Andrew Что значит сделать их "drity"? Не могу понять

Comment: у ячеек есть состояние. dirty state это когда ячейку нужно принудительно обновить. Обычно с сохранением данных в датасет. В принципе гугл подскажет как это делать.

Comment: Есть метод `Invalidate()`. Его можно применить хоть к строке, хоть к колонке, хоть ко всей таблице. `Refresh()` не сработает, пока не изменится `DataSource`. Вызывайте `Invalidate()`, и не надо велосипедов с dirty.

Comment: @aepot По `Invalidate()` мало информации, как именно его вызвать? Нужно ли мне удалить `dataSet.Tables["tbl_orders"].Clear()`? Как бы я его не вызывал, у меня все равно дублируются данные.

Comment: Нужен воспроизводимый пример без участия БД. Дублируются колонки или строки?

Comment: @aepot Есть только похожий проект на XML, [ссылка](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19BSjcRDc5aZfCEzDU1FFHXNOMub-WbvE/view?usp=sharing). Там тоже без `Clear()` данные дублируются при нажатии Update.

Comment: В примере все не так как надо сделано. Почему две таблицы грузятся в один датагрид? При чем тут FileSystemWatcher? Какие-то пустые строки в DGV добавляются. Я не могу понять, что именно здесь воспроизводится? А какая задача решается? Вы можете создать нормальный простой пример пусть даже на базе того же XML, хотя-бы из 2 колонок, который не работает как хотелось бы?

Comment: @aepot `FileSystemWatcher` не нужен, поэтому я его и закомментировал. Это просто старый тестовый проект, и не важно добавляются пустые строки или нет. Главная суть это перезагрузить данные в таблицу с сохранением позиции скролла. Можно просто нажимать там кнопку Update, и смотреть как себя ведет DGV.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/MUCtHlQfbwPB1A - вот, поправил пример. Обратите внимание, я вообще нигде не взаимодействую с ячейками таблицы, вместо этого я взаимодействую с датасетом, а таблица обновляется сама. В конструкторе формы все колонки удалены, используются колонки из датасета. Для перезагрузки данных в таблицу использую `Clear()` для `DataTable`. Никаких `Refresh()` или `Invalidate()` вообще не требуется. Надеюсь, идея понятна.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за пример, но метод обновления мне как раз таки был нужен, так как программа многопользовательская, и мне нужно вызвать метод обновления при определенных событиях. `dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[column]` это то же самое что `dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Selected = true`. Получается этот пример такой же какой у меня был изначально, скролл так же дергается.

Comment: Ну, так вы все данные перечитываете, сделовательно и табличка вся переобновляется. Чтобы избежать этого, вам нужно просто добавлять или удалять строки из `DataTable`, типа `dt.Add("111","222");` В этом случае не надо вызывать `Clear()` и перезаписывать позицию выбранной ячейки, и скролл не будет дергаться. Но вы изначально сказали про дублирование данных, я просто показал пример, где его нет. То есть, возникло событие, грузите данные, сверяете, и обновляете свой `DataTable` добавлением и удалением строк. Вот и вся магия. Ну либо сервер должен слать, что именно откуда убрать или добавить.

Comment: Есть такая БД у гугла - FireBase, она умеет слать уведомления об изменении данных подписанным на них приложениям. Ну либо другие БД посмотрите, которые так умеют. Весь смысл во внесении изменений в `DataTable`, каких именно и как - решать вам. DGV здесь не при чем, она только отображает содержимое DT.

Comment: Модераторы, дайте мне возможность минусовать комменты! Задрало использование метода `Refresh` у gui-контролов! Постоянно вижу, как его лепят не к месту. Неоднократно писал об этом.

Comment: @Andrew - метод `Refresh` **никак** не связан с привязкой данных. Он по сути вызывает **перерисовку** контрола.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov буду знать, спасибо что отписал об этом. Вот что значит плохое название у метода, его нужно было назвать "Redraw" и никто бы не путал :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Способ:
   Без очистки `DataTable` - это добавить `dataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey`. Но он очень тормознутый.
2. Способ:
   Сохранить свойство `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` перед загрузкой `DataSource` и назначить его после загрузки.

```
private void ReloadData()
{
    int row = dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;

    dataTable.Clear();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;

    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count != 0)
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = row;
}
```